# System.OverflowException in serialization

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, serialization, windows-phone-8, overflowexception

I have a some classes for parse the web response:

```
[DataContract]
public abstract class GYResponse 
{
    [DataMember(Name = "code")]
    public int Code { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class ResponseGetUser : GYResponse
{
    [DataMember(Name = "result")]
    public GYUser Result { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class ResponseGetVenue : GYResponse
{
    [DataMember(Name = "result")]
    public GYVenue Result { get; set; }
}
```

I use `DataContractJsonSerializer`:

```
GYResponse response_obj = request.Creater.CreateResponseObj(); 
//CreateResponseObj() return ResponseGetUser, ResponseGetVenue etc

using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(gyResponse)))
{
    DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(response_obj.GetType());                   
    response_obj = (GYResponse)serializer.ReadObject(stream);       
}
```

I have `"System.OverflowException"` in line:

```
response_obj = (GYResponse)serializer.ReadObject(stream);
```

The /checked compiler option is off. And `ReadObject` can't throw this exception.

But if I rewrite the classes then it works:

```
[DataContract]
public abstract class GYResponse 
{

}

[DataContract]
public class ResponseGetUser : GYResponse
{
    [DataMember(Name = "result")]
    public GYUser Result { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "code")]
    public int Code { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class ResponseGetVenue : GYResponse
{
    [DataMember(Name = "result")]
    public GYVenue Result { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "code")]
    public int Code { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

I understand that this is a fuzzy question, but can't understand what could be the problem. At what point can throw this exception?

**Update exception info:**

Message:

```
 There was an error deserializing the object of type GotYou.RequesterService.ResponseGetInfo. Value was either too large or too small for an Int32.
```

InnerException:

```
at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at System.String.System.IConvertible.ToInt32(IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer.ConvertObjectToPrimitiveDataContract(DataContract contract, Object value, XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplexJson context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer.ConvertObjectToDataContract(DataContract contract, Object value, XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplexJson context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.ObjectToDataContractConverter.ReadClassDataContractMembers(DataContractJsonSerializer serializer, ClassDataContract dataContract, Dictionary`2 deserialzedValue, Object newInstance, XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplexJson context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.ObjectToDataContractConverter.ReadClassDataContractMembers(DataContractJsonSerializer serializer, ClassDataContract dataContract, Dictionary`2 deserialzedValue, Object newInstance, XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplexJson context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.ObjectToDataContractConverter.ConvertDictionaryToClassDataContract(DataContractJsonSerializer serializer, ClassDataContract dataContract, Dictionary`2 deserialzedValue, XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplexJson context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer.ConvertObjectToDataContract(DataContract contract, Object value, XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplexJson context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.ObjectToDataContractConverter.ReadClassDataContractMembers(DataContractJsonSerializer serializer, ClassDataContract dataContract, Dictionary`2 deserialzedValue, Object newInstance, XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplexJson context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.ObjectToDataContractConverter.ConvertDictionaryToClassDataContract(DataContractJsonSerializer serializer, ClassDataContract dataContract, Dictionary`2 deserialzedValue, XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplexJson context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer.ConvertObjectToDataContract(DataContract contract, Object value, XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplexJson context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.ObjectToDataContractConverter.ReadClassDataContractMembers(DataContractJsonSerializer serializer, ClassDataContract dataContract, Dictionary`2 deserialzedValue, Object newInstance, XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplexJson context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.ObjectToDataContractConverter.ConvertDictionaryToClassDataContract(DataContractJsonSerializer serializer, ClassDataContract dataContract, Dictionary`2 deserialzedValue, XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplexJson context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer.ConvertObjectToDataContract(DataContract contract, Object value, XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplexJson context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer.ReadObject(Stream stream)
```

StrackTrace:

```
 at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer.ReadObject(Stream stream)
   at GotYou.RequesterService.PostRequester.getResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
```

Json Response:

```
{
    "code": 0,
    "message": "",
    "result": {
        "uid": "51da997decaa3ca351000000",
        "url": "",
        "nickname": "Smileman",
        "avatar": "\/img\/profile_pics\/users\/51da997decaa3ca351000000\/cache\/avatar48x48.jpg?lastUpdate=1381215566",
        "age": {
            "number": "22",
            "suffix": "года",
            "birthday": "1991-04-17"
        },
        "sex": 1,
        "aboutself": "",
        "premium": true,
        "isFriend": 3,
        "online": {
            "lastVisit": "7 минут назад",
            "status": true
        },
        "features": {
            "car": false,
            "house": false,
            "cash": false,
            "group": true
        },
        "location": {
            "longitude": 36.570838832,
            "latitude": 50.571069472,
            "timestamp": 1381319677
        },
        "bonuses": 8515,
        "address": "",
        "city": {
            "code": "3100000100000",
            "title": ""
        },
        "cover": "\/img\/profile_pics\/users\/51da997decaa3ca351000000\/cache\/hero480x290.jpg?lastUpdate=1381215566",
        "distance": 63.671441859659,
        "paidServices": {
            "vip": true,
            "theming": true,
            "invisible": false,
            "incognito": false,
            "closed": true
        },
        "regdate": "19.08.2013",
        "purpose": {
            "id": "500fa718ecaa3c6e3b000002",
            "title": ""
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the *full* exception stack trace. That's likely to make things a bit clearer. It would also help if you'd show the data in question.

Comment: So are you serializing a big object ?

Comment: @sino but why it work after change abstract class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This number: `3100000100000` in your data is too large for [`Int32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.aspx) to hold it. Maximum positive value for [`Int32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.aspx) is  `2147483647`. You might consider using [`Int64`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int64.aspx) ([`UInt32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uint32.aspx) will also be too small, as its range ends at `4294967295`).

However, `code` fields are usually interpreted as strings, so maybe `string` data type is a better option, for example:

```
[DataMember(Name = "code")]
public string Code { get; set; }
```

Comment: but code is string "code": "3100000100000", for example timestamp is Int32  "timestamp": 1381319677

Comment: In your implementation it's not a string, you have: `[DataMember(Name = "code")] public int Code { get; set; }` so during the deserialization this large number is being converted to an integer.

Comment: ohhh!I understand, you are very attentive! Thank you!